# Select columns until find a value

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to find the Visual Basic command to select a nonspecific number of columns. For example, I have a list of values in a row and I have to select them from the first column until I'll find a "5". How can I do this?

Comment: Can you clarify your example? Sometimes the best way to learn how to do this in VBA is to record a macro - follow the steps you would do solve it in excel. Then review the code afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this quickly find Find, which also enables a "not found" result by testing if rng1 exists post find

to search in row 1 of the activesheet for a variable strfind and higlight from column A to the found value

```
Sub QuickFind()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim strFind As String
    strFind = "5"
    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(strFind, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If rng1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox strFind & " not found"
    Else
        Range(rng1, rng1.End(xlToLeft)).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 For using the find method.  Perhaps add: SearchOrder:=xlByColumns

Comment: Thx Reafidy :). This could probably have been added as Find will apply the prior search order, I left it out as the code currently searches a single row. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Public Function Search(row As Integer) As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    col = 1

    While ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col) <> "5"
      col = col + 1
    Wend
    Search = col
End Function
```